# postfix in docker cannot resolve hostname of relay host

Tags: dns, docker, postfix, nslookup, relay

My postfix instance running in a docker container seems to be unable to resolve the hostname of my relay which is outbound.mailhop.org (formerly Oracle and now owned by DuoCircle).

Relay fails with the following message:

```
Apr  5 14:59:27 smtp postfix/smtp[103]: 10E6F481F6D: to=<xxx@googlemail.com>, relay=none, delay=938, delays=938/0.03/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=outbound.mailhop.org type=A: Host not found, try again)
```

In the setup above I used the A record lookup like this:

```
relayhost = [outbound.mailhop.org]:465
```

But also the MX record lookup fails:

```
relayhost = outbound.mailhop.org:465
```

To analyze the problem I extended the `debian:stable-slim` image to contain the `dnsutils` package and started an interactive `bash` shell inside the container. There I can lookup `outbound.mailhop.org` using `nslookup` or `dig` without any issues.

The only other thing related I could think of was nscd. The package unscd is required for postfix to even start. However according to `/etc/nscd.conf` which states:

```
enable-cache hosts no
```

Any lookups should always address the name server directly.

I really don't get why `nslookup` and `dig` work but `postfix` shows problems.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the reason for my issues was the fact that in `master.cf` the `relay` subprogram was configured to run in a `chroot` which is located in `/var/spool/postfix`. Since in my container there is neither a `/etc/hosts` or a `/etc/resolv.conf` relative to the chroot directory it is not surprising that postfix could not properly resolve host names.

- At first I made it work just copying my existing `/etc/resolv.conf` to the chroot directory.
- Running postfix in a docker container - which is like a chroot on steroids - I later changed `master.cf` to disable chrooting for all postfix subprograms.